# Given the equation $x = \sqrt{y}$, does the equation represent y as a function of x?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I can justify why the answer might be no, but also why it might be yes, so which line of reasoning is correct?

I. **$x=\sqrt{y}$ does not represent y as a function of x** because if $x$ is a negative number, then no corresponding y-value can be made, and by definition an equation is a function only if each x-value has exactly one corresponding y-value.

or

II. **$x = \sqrt{y}$ does represent y as a function of x** because solving the equation for $y$ yields $y=x^2$ with the domain restricted to [0,$\infty$), and graphing this yields half a parabola that passes the Vertical Line Test.

Comment: Would you also say that $\tan x$ isn’t a function of $x$?

Answer (score 1):

Your option 2 is correct, as long as we add a bit of clarification:

- The equation $x = \sqrt{y}$ represents $y$ as a function of $x$ *on the domain* $x \ge 0$.

Functions only make sense when they are defined on a particular domain, i.e. a set of input values. Once we make that clear, then we can check that your given equation does indeed meet the requirements of a function, most importantly that for any given $x$ value, there is only one valid $y$ value.

Comment: Thank you for the response. However, the problem I am currently working does not specify the domain, so I simply assumed the domain was all real values. If the domain was indeed all real values, would option 2 still be correct?

Comment: Functions have domains. You're saying that you have an equation. Equations are not intended to be functions. In equations, you're solving for an unknown. They're made up of variables and constants. You need to get your terminology straight.

Comment: If the domain was all real numbers, then $x = \sqrt{y}$ would not define $y$ as a real-valued function of $x$ since there is no real value of $y$ such that $-1 = \sqrt{y}$.

Answer (score 0):

Does the expression $x=\sqrt{y}$ represent a function? The answer is yes. [A function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)) is a mapping of values from one set of real numbers (typically, real numbers), $A$, to another set of real numbers, $B$. The important thing with functions is that each element in $A$ should be associated with exactly one element in $B$. Is this true of $x=\sqrt{y}$? Well, $y$ can assume all possible nonnegative numbers and each such number when put throught the square root function will spit out exactly one $x$ value associated with that particular $y$ value that you plug in. Does this meet the criteria that make a relation of two sets of numbers a function? Yes, it does. So, $x=\sqrt{y}$ as a function of $y$ is a function with the domain $x\ge 0$ since the process of square-rooting can only give you numbers that are nonnegative and the range $y\ge 0$ because the only values you are allowed to take the square root of are those that are nonnegative. Again, I assume we're only working with real numbers.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different uses of the word "function".  Usually in mathematics, a function is a mapping from one set to another and part of the definition includes specifying the domain.

However, science and engineering types use the phrase "is a function of" to mean "depends on".  More precisely, they would say "$y$ is a function of $x$" to mean "if you know $x$, then $y$ is determined."  In this context, the answer to your question, "Is $y$ a function of $x$?" is "Yes, because if I know $x$ then I know $y$."   And if $x$ is negative, then I know $y$ doesn't exist.

If you allow complex numbers, then the situation is different.  If you know $x$ then $y$ could be one of two numbers, and we wouldn't say that $y$ is a function of $x$.